Why two queries with very different EXPLAIN plan cost estimate run in the same time?
I am trying to optimize the index of my table table. For this I have created two indices index_a and index_b.
When I run EXPLAIN plan. The cost for index_a reads as:
Index Only Scan using index_a on table  (cost=0.70..24,883 rows=400,000)
And the cost for index_b:
Index Scan using index_b on table  (cost=0.70..1,518,150 rows=400,000)
But the actual run time of both queries is the same or very similar in the end. What may be happening here? Could it be related to the number of rows?

Cost is synthetic estimate of the work required to execute the query: it is not a reliable predictor of execution time. Please add the full output from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS,SETTINGS,VERBOSE) as well as the relevant DDL (including index definitions) and a description of the data characteristics. Without this additional information, any further attempts at explanation would be pure speculation.

Check chapters 14.1 and 14.2: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/performance-tips.html
